# 3 week old brand new Montra Rock 1.0 front gears don't change as well chain slips frequently

Tags: mountain-bike

I bought a Montra Rock 1.0 MTB 3 weeks back, I use it mostly on city roads.

For the past 4 days I have noticed that the front gear does not change. It stays on lower gear and if try to change it chain slips frequently and there is a rattling sound at pedals.

What is ideal front-back gear combo for city roads?

Comment: Normal cable stretch in a new bike. Take it to the shop they'll adjust it in a matter of minutes!

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles.SE! Your last paragraph is a whole different question. Since Bicycles.SE is a Q&A board, not a general discussion board, you should ask it as a separate question instead of tacking it on to this one. Taking the [Tour](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/tour) will help you get acquainted with the _SE Way™_.

Comment: First, make sure the slipping are not cause by sharp angle between FD and RD. FD largest chainring must not cross to RD largest chainring, same to smallest to smallest. Second, make sure you NEVER shift under tension.  If both are false, then proceed to checking the rest.

Answer (score 3):

Ensure the shifter is set to the low position - the position where the chain is on the smallest chain ring.  Give the cable a tug, it should be taut but not tight. You can make minor tension adjustments by turning the barrel adjuster near the front shifter-to-cable housing connection.  If you can not take up enough slack with the barrel adjuster, screw it in about 3/4 the way and then loosen the cable at the front dérailleur and pull out the slack in the cable and retighten. Make the final adjustments with the barrel adjuster near the shifter. It should take about 2 minutes for correct.

If you continue to have shifting problems it can be the angle of the derailleur or the position of the set (stop) screws. In that case if you are comfortable making adjustments look to YouTube for instructions, otherwise, take it into a shop.